# Selenium: WebDriver "get" function returns a string

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to develop a browser automation with selenium. I need to download HTML sources and analyze them. I'm writing my code like this:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
htmlDoc300 = browser.page_source
error_text = htmlDoc300.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ModalErrorText').text
```

The last line returns the error "'str' object has no attribute 'find_element", so "page_source" returns a string and not a driver. How can i fix it? Is it possible to cast the str in a webDrvier?

Comment: You need to be calling .find_element() on your webdriver directly - ```browser.find_element(By.ID, "element_ID")```. See [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_element_by_id-driver-method-selenium-python/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend, browser.page_source returns the HTML content which is of an str datatype.

```
print(type(browser.page_source))
>> <class 'str'>
```

and as you get the error, str doesn't have "find_element" attribute.

```
print(type(browser))
>> <class 'selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver'>
```

I hope you noticed the difference. So you need to find your desired element on the browser itself like this :

```
error_text = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ModalErrorText').text
```